# HMM Application for Kinect in C# WPF

Tags: c#, hidden-markov-models

I want to apply Hidden Markov Model to Kinect with C# WPF API.I'm not sure that if it is possible or not? What do you think about that? This is a good work or not? I mean some friends says that C++ or Matlab is better application API. But, I don't know those ones. I haven't found any HMM C# sample codes on the web. Should I start? Thanks for any commend.

Comment: Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69647/Hidden-Markov-Models-in-C ?
I'm still working through understanding the source code.